# Direct access to unique class data member

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, memory-address

I have a class with a unique public data member which is a built-in type:

```
class foo {
public:
    int data;

    foo(int dataIn) : data(dataIn) {}
    virtual ~foo() {}

    // Some other class methods
protected:
    // Some internal helper class methods
};
```

In an other class, I would like to use `memcpy` method:

```
template<typename T>class bar {
protected:
    T data;
public:
    bar() {}
    virtual ~bar() {}

    void read(unsigned char* readBuff, const std::size_t &readSize) {
        // Some stuff
        std::memcpy(readBuff, &(this->data), readSize);
        // Some stuff
    }
};
```

The idea would be `bar` to be usable when `T` is a built-in type or an instance of `foo`.

But is T is `foo` and therefore `data` in `bar` a `foo` instance, am I insured that reading from the element pointed by `&(this->data)` will be `data` in `foo`?

When I run this:

```
foo x(12);
std::cout << sizeof(foo);
```

I get `4`, so foo seems to be exactly the size of an int, so I would naturally think that directly reading/writing to `x` even without specifying `x.data` would write to data. Is it true?

I need to be C++11-compatible.

Comment: You can use `offsetof`.

Comment: "If you allocate an object of that type, and get a `byte*` to the start of the structure, you can uses `offsetof` to find out where each member is. If you use that pointer offset, and convert it back to the correct type, it will give you a pointer to the member." -- [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3391349/5267751).

Comment: @user202729 `offsetof` states: "type shall be a standard-layout class (including unions)." and "A standard-layout class is a class [...] that: (1) has no virtual functions and no virtual base classes."

Comment: @user202729 as WorldSEnder said, documentation says it is undefined behaviour in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The layout of an arbitrary type with virtual members is implementation defined. You are not guaranteed to have `data` at an offset of 0 in foo.

You can instead fully specialise `bar` for `foo`.

```
template<>class bar<foo> {
protected:
    foo data;
public:
    bar() {}
    virtual ~bar() {}

    void write(unsigned char* readBuff, const std::size_t &readSize) {
        // Some stuff
        std::memcpy(readBuff, &(this->data.data), readSize);
        // Some stuff
    }
};
```

If the duplication of the rest of `bar` is a problem, you can write a helper template

```
template<typename T> bar_helper
{
    void* operator()(T & data) { return &data; }
}

template<> bar_helper<foo>
{
    void* operator()(foo & data) { return &data.data; }
}

template<typename T>
void bar<T>::write(unsigned char* readBuff, const std::size_t &readSize) {
    // Some stuff
    bar_helper<T> helper;
    std::memcpy(readBuff, helper(this->data), readSize);
    // Some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No.

For class with virtual function, normally compiler will insert some meta data at the beginning of the class. You can't assume the address of an instance is also the address of its first member.

You can use `if constexpr` to distinguish these 2 cases:

```
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, foo> ) {
        std::memcpy(readBuff, &(this->data.data), readSize);
    } else {
        std::memcpy(readBuff, &(this->data), readSize);
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that I need to be c++11-compliant. if constexpr doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

After several tries, I found another way to implement it without having to instantiate a new `helper` object in read() as in @Caleth's solution (which is very good though), so which should have better performance:

```
class foo {
public:
    int data;

    foo(int dataIn) : data(dataIn) {}
    virtual ~foo() {}

    // Some other class methods
protected:
    // Some internal helper class methods
};

template<bool ISFOO> struct IsFoo_ {
    enum {
        IS_FOO_ = ISFOO
    };
};

template<typename T>class bar {
protected:
    T data;
public:
    bar() {}
    virtual ~bar() {}

    struct CRV {
        enum {
            USES_FOO = std::is_same<T, foo>::value
        };
    };

    void* getCopyable() {
        return getCopyable_<CRV::USES_FOO>();
    }

    void read(unsigned char* readBuff, const std::size_t &readSize) {
        // Some stuff
        std::memcpy(readBuff, this->getCopyable(), readSize);
        // Some stuff
    }

private:
    // Caller method
    template<bool ISFOO> inline void* getCopyable_() {
        return getCopyable_(IsBitVector_<ISFOO>());
    }
    // Generic method
    template<bool ISFOO> inline void* getCopyable_(IsFoo_<ISFOO>) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    // Specializations
    inline void* getCopyable_(IsFoo_<true>) {
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(&(this->data.data));
    }
    inline void* getCopyable_(IsFoo_<false>) {
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(&(this->data));
    }
};
```

Comment: An empty struct's `operator()` is just as likely to be inlined as all those template members

Comment: Yep you are probably right. I'll accept your answer anyway ;-). The real problem is that I oversimplified my question (foo is actually a template class in my original code) so your answer (which is great!) would not work for my original code.